# Is this construction valid "since what age is it allowed to do something"?

Tags: construction

Is this construction correct?

**Since what age is it** allowed to drive?

**Since what age was she** allowed to work there?

Comment: Hopelessly ambiguous as well as unnatural! Does age refer to her age or the age of the institution where she works - as in **since when**

Answer (score 3):

The more natural construction is:

- "**From what age** are you allowed to drive".

"You" here means anyone, not the person being addressed.

The second sentence has an ambiguity. Do you mean when was it legal for her to work there? In that case it's

- "**From what age** was she allowed to work there?"

If you want to know how old she was when she started working there:

- "How old was she when she started working there?"
- "How long has she worked there?"

Comment: ... you could also use **at what age** in these sentences.

Comment: Or, more formally, "from what age **is one** allowed to drive".